# Get first element in relation with Eloquent Builder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve a user's answer. I have this query :

```
$data = Category::where('id', $id)->with(
            [
                'questions' => function ($query) {
                    $query->with(['answers' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where( 'user_id', auth()->user()->id )->first();
                    } ])->orderBy('position', 'ASC');
                }
            ]
        )->first();
```

I would like to collect only the answer (a user can only have one answer to a question)

But laravel returns an array "answers"

[image]

How to have only the answer, without this array? Thank you !

Comment: I think the problem is on your relationships, or.. is there any special requirement to have manyToMany realtionship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define another relationship called `answer` and make it a `hasOne`. This way you only get 1 result, however note that without an order (order by) the result can change from request to request.